# Cómo podría ocultar el número telefónico al realizar una llamada desde Android

Tags: android-studio

He estado intentando ocultar el número teléfonico en la pantalla del celular, esto para una utilidad de conmutador en mi edificio, no quiero que se muestre el número al que se llama. Los números los obtengo desde un "properties" (context) de Android. Soy nuevo en Android y no he encontrado como realizarlo.

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        call_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        call_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String condomino = null;
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                condomino = et.getText().toString();

                String valor = null;
                try {
                    et.setText(Util.getProperty(condomino, getApplicationContext()));
                    et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + et.getText().toString());
                Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
                startActivity(surf);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto en realidad no es posible (posiblemente por seguridad), si realizas el marcado telefónico mediante un `Intent` usando `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`, este tendrá que mostrar el número al que se llamara dede la aplicación.

```
Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + et.getText().toString());
Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]